# mysql update row based on field value

Tags: mysql

How can I update a field in mysql based on the previous value?

Lets say that `count` equals 3.

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET count = count-1
```

Will that work? so the new value of count would be 4

Comment: ALso, how can I add negative numbers? I tried the above with count-1 but it says zero rows affected when count is zero. The result should be -1 ?

Comment: Yes. That will work -- however it would update every row in the table. Is this what you're intending? If not then you should specify the row you want to update in a WHERE clause.

Comment: It depends on the column type : -1 for a signed integer (negatives are allowed), 0 for an unsigned integer (negatives not allowed).

Comment: count is int and I'm already adding a where clause.

Comment: I think I got it now. I had my where clause wrong and wasn't updating the rows I wanted. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean for the row or the table? If you mean on insert or update for a row you can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try and it worked, so perhaps you need to show us the CREATE statement for the table. Test results:

```
mysql> create table aint ( count int not null default 0 );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)

mysql> insert into aint VALUES(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from aint;
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update aint set count = count-1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from aint;
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update aint set count = count-1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from aint;
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|    -1 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```